# problem in connection in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: internet, connection

I have problem in ubuntu version 20.04
my connection is wired and there is no internet connection.

I do some solution like, changing DNS (8.8.8.8),
changing the IP address manually
and I still having the same problem so, there is any recommended solution?

Comment: What are you wired to? Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: A sidenote, there is no `20.4` version, just a `20.04` - edited to remedy that.
note that `DHCP` requires a present DHCP-server, either your own (e.g. in a router), or one at your internet service provider (ISP). If that is not present then you need to massage all the numbers manually, with suitable information provided by the "one" that knows how things are set up.